# RegEx for # in user password but prevents # in SQL injection

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find a regex combination that will allow the user's password through for a symbol but will still validate that symbol for SQL injections.

E.g. will allow for user password to be password#123, but will not allow any of the following commands:

```
admin' #
admin'/*
' or 1=1--
' or 1=1#
```

or SQL injections using # in general.

I tried this and it worked. Is there a reason not to use it from a security perspective?

```
(?<!\s)#(?!\s)
```

Comment: Sorry, but this question is underspecified. Please clearly state your goals and constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason not to use it from a security perspective?

**Yes**, it sound like you are storing your passwords in plaintext in your database, which is generally a bad idea.
A password should always be encrypted respectively hashed.

If the password is hashed you don't have to worry about SQL injection.